# Samba share on second hard drive not accessible... contact the administrator

Tags: permissions, samba, drive, sharing

I setup Ubuntu Server 18.04 and installed Samba. Then I added a second drive of 6T to use for file storage and share after successfully creating and accessing a share on the primary drive.  After reading many forums and making many attempts to correct the problem I still get the share not accessible... Contact the administrator of this server...

Drive:
sdb1, ext 4, mount point is /data

fstab:
/dev/sdb1 /data ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 2

I created a directory under /data named /movies for my first share.

Here is the smb.conf entry:

```
[movies]
path = /data/movies
browseable = yes
read only = no
valid users = movies
```

The user movies was created in both Ubuntu and Samba with the same pwd.

My thinking so far is that either I am not referencing something correctly or I am missing permissions somewhere.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Are you accessing the share as user `movies`?

Comment: Yes.  Trying to keep it simple for now.  The directory is movies and the user is movies.  I have read numerous forums about the security but none of them have helped me gain access.   I presume I need to create the shared folder in the mount point for it to use the 6T drive.  Is that correct?

Comment: I made everything owned by a user1, let people sign on w/own userid and then `force user user1` in the config file. Who owns client side mount points? For me forcing was only way it worked, but I am no expert.

Comment: I changed the ownership to a user other than root.  I presume you mean to force the user in the smb.conf file. what parameters do I use to do that with?

Comment: Thank you Organic Marble.,  All I really needed was to create a user to own the shared folder other than root.  I read up on the forced user parameter but I did not need to use it.  I have few tweaks to make but I am up and running.
How do I give you the credit for answering this for me?

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. I will write a formal answer below, which you can accept if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments, I described the configuration I used, which allowed the OP to determine a solution.

> I made everything owned by a `user1`, let people sign on w/own userid
>   and then `force user user1` in the config file. Who owns client side
>   mount points? For me forcing was only way it worked, but I am no
>   expert.

The OP stated that based on this comment, they created a user other than root to own the shared folder. This resulted in the desired functionality. They did not have to force the user.